# How to access chrome storage from multiple HTML files in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I already have an options page on my chrome extension, and I am trying to create several other pages in my extension directory which need to make use of the chrome storage data gathered by popup.html.

I have tried adding the new HTML page to the options page attribute in the manifest.json file, but that prevents the extension from loading. When accessing the chrome storage with a "DOMContentLoaded" event on the new non-options HTML page, as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    getData();
}, false);

function getData() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['data'], function (result) {
        console.log(result.data);
        setFormData(result.data[0])
    });
}


function setFormData(data){
    console.log(data)
}
```

I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

I assume means that newHTML.html is not making use of the manifest file, but I am note sure how I tell the manifest file about newHTML.

Here is the manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "ExtensionName!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A Chrome Extension!",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage","<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "options_page": "formMenu.html",
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.fontawesome.com; object-src 'self'",
    "externally_connectable": {
      "ids": ["*"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: If your manifest permissions contain `"storage"`, this should work. Can you show your manifest.json ?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I just added the manifest to my question, which does allow storage and storage does work in popup.html and in formMenu.html.

Comment: Do you access newHTML.html through `chrome-extension://[id]/newHTML.html` ?

Comment: I haven't been accessing it that way @Jean-Alphonse as I do not how to integrate into the extension though it is in the extension folder. I have just accessing the newHTML in the directory (file:///...).

Comment: Well that's your problem ! Within the context of your extension, you can get this special url with `chrome.runtime.getURL("newHTML.html")`

Comment: lol. That works, and that is how I was opening the options page. I just didn't think it was the manner of linking that did it. I guess its the fact that a tab is created (using chrome.tabs.create) from within the extension. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has acces to `chrome.storage` *when it is running in the context of your extension*.
If you open `file://.../newHTML.html`, it's just a normal javascript context.

Use `chrome.runtime.getURL("newHTML.html")` to get an extension url which looks like this: `chrome-extension://[id]/newHTML.html`.

Also there is no need to wait for DOMContentLoaded to acces localStorage.